# MapFragment as child in ExpandableListAdapter - preserve touch events

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have `ExpandableListView` with adapter. This is list of localizations. As childs on each item i use `MapFragment`, but when map is visible touching events working on listview, not on map. How to block touching events for listview when i touching a map ?

Comment: Try setting the xml attribute on the listview: `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: I'd suggest having only one map with pins representing a list of addresses in a (expandable) list view. Your current solution is going to be an enormous performance hog, difficult to navigate and goes against expected activity flow.

Comment: Yes, I have one instance of `MapFragment` with all localizations on it. On itemClick i reuse this fragment as child and move map camera to selected location. I didn't see any performance issues. Maybe You right that using map as child in `ExpandableListView` is not good design pattern, but i need this like that.